# "The precision is invalid" during insert from stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, vb6, adodb

I am trying to insert values ​​from VB6 to SQL Server with a stored procedure but when I want to execute the process, I get this error:

> The precision is invalid

I have already changed so many times the way that I try to enter them that I no longer know what to do.

This is the code in VB6

```vb
Dim strSQL As String
strSQL = "INSERT INTO FacturasPendientes (IdFactura,FechaFactura,CodigoProveedor,NombreProveedor," _
       & " SubTotal,Iva,Total,FechaVencimiento,DiasDescuento,DescProntoPago,Pagado) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"

Dim CmdCont As ADODB.Command
Set CmdCont = New ADODB.Command

With CmdCont
    Set .ActiveConnection = Cnn
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandText = "sp_FacturasCompras"
    .Parameters.Append CmdCont.CreateParameter("@IdFactura", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, TxtFactura.Text)
    .Parameters.Append CmdCont.CreateParameter("@FechaFactura", adDate, adParamInput, 50, dtpFactura.Value)
    .Parameters.Append CmdCont.CreateParameter("@CodigoProveedor", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, TxtCodigoProveedor.Text)
    .Parameters.Append CmdCont.CreateParameter("@NombreProveedor", adVarChar, adParamInput, 100, txtProveedor.Text)
    .Parameters.Append CmdCont.CreateParameter("@SubTotal", adNumeric, adParamInput, 18, Round(Val(m_Subtotal), 2))
    .Parameters.Append CmdCont.CreateParameter("@Iva", adNumeric, adParamInput, 18, Round(Val(m_Iva), 2))
    .Parameters.Append CmdCont.CreateParameter("@Total", adNumeric, adParamInput, 18, Round(Val(m_Total), 2))
    .Parameters.Append CmdCont.CreateParameter("@FechaVencimiento", adDate, adParamInput, 50, FechaFinal)
    .Parameters.Append CmdCont.CreateParameter("@DiasDescuento", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, txtDias.Text)
    .Parameters.Append CmdCont.CreateParameter("@DescProntoPago", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, txtDescuento.Text)
    .Parameters.Append CmdCont.CreateParameter("@Pagado", adBigInt, adParamInput, chkPago.Value)
    .Prepared = True
    .Execute
End With
MsgBox "Se Grabaron los datos"
```

And the stored procedure is this:

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_FacturasCompras] 
    -- agregamos los valores de la consulta
    @IdFactura VARCHAR(50),
    @FechaFactura DATE,
    @CodigoProveedor VARCHAR(50),
    @NombreProveedor VARCHAR(100),
    @SubTotal NUMERIC(18),
    @Iva NUMERIC(18),
    @Total NUMERIC(18),
    @FechaVencimiento DATE,
    @DiasDescuento VARCHAR(50),
    @DescProntoPago VARCHAR(50),
    @Pagado BIGINT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO FacturasPendientes (IdFactura, FechaFactura, CodigoProveedor, NombreProveedor,
                                    SubTotal, Iva, Total, FechaVencimiento, 
                                    DiasDescuento, DescProntoPago, Pagado)
    VALUES (@IdFactura, @FechaFactura, @CodigoProveedor, @NombreProveedor,
            @SubTotal, @Iva, @Total, @FechaVencimiento,
            @DiasDescuento, @DescProntoPago, @Pagado)
END
```

Comment: You are passing `chkPago.Value` for the `Size` argument for `@Pagado`. I would also remove the sizes from the date parameters.

Comment: It's a **STORED** procedure - as in stored inside SQL Server - it has nothing to do with "storage" ......

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is with the `adNumeric` columns.  Try code like the following:

```
Dim p As Parameter

With CmdCont
   Set p = .CreateParameter("@SubTotal", adNumeric, adParamInput)
   p.Precision = 18
   p.NumericScale = 2
   p.Value = Round(Val(m_Subtotal), 2)
   .Parameters.Append p
End With
```

You can adjust the precision and scale as needed.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to call a stored procedure is to use `Cnn` connection object like this

```
Cnn.sp_FacturasCompras TxtFactura.Text, dtpFactura.Value, _
    TxtCodigoProveedor.Text, txtProveedor.Text, _
    Round(Val(m_Subtotal), 2), Round(Val(m_Iva), 2), _
    Round(Val(m_Total), 2), FechaFinal, txtDias.Text, _
    txtDescuento.Text, chkPago.Value
```

. . . which looks like an ordinary method call on the `Cnn` object.

If you **have** to use `ADODB.Command` then best would be to use some helper function for initializing `ADODB.Parameter` instances and `ADODB.Command` instances like this

```
Option Explicit

Private m_Subtotal      As Double
Private m_Iva           As Double
Private m_Total         As Double

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim oCmd As ADODB.Command

    Set oCmd = InitCommandHelper("sp_FacturasCompras", _
        InitParamHelper(TxtFactura.Text, adVarChar, 50), _
        InitParamHelper(dtpFactura.Value, adDBDate), _
        InitParamHelper(TxtCodigoProveedor.Text, adVarChar, 50), _
        InitParamHelper(txtProveedor.Text, adVarChar, 100), _
        InitParamHelper(Round(Val(m_Subtotal), 2), adDecimal, Precision:=18, NumericScale:=2), _
        InitParamHelper(Round(Val(m_Iva), 2), adDecimal, Precision:=18, NumericScale:=2), _
        InitParamHelper(Round(Val(m_Total), 2), adDecimal, Precision:=18, NumericScale:=2), _
        InitParamHelper(FechaFinal, adVarChar, 50), _
        InitParamHelper(txtDias.Text, adVarChar, 50), _
        InitParamHelper(txtDescuento.Text, adVarChar, 50), _
        InitParamHelper(chkPago.Value, adBigInt))
    Debug.Print oCmd.Parameters.Count
End Sub

Public Function InitCommandHelper( _
            ByVal sStoredProc As String, _
            ParamArray Params() As Variant) As ADODB.Command
    Const FUNC_NAME     As String = "InitCommandHelper"
    Dim lIdx            As Long

    On Error GoTo EH
    Set InitCommandHelper = New ADODB.Command
    With InitCommandHelper
        If InStr(sStoredProc, ".") > 0 Then
            .CommandText = sStoredProc
        Else
            .CommandText = "dbo." & sStoredProc
        End If
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("RetVal", adInteger, adParamReturnValue)
        lIdx = LBound(Params)
        Do While lIdx <= UBound(Params)
            .Parameters.Append Params(lIdx)
            lIdx = lIdx + 1
        Loop
    End With
    Exit Function
EH:
    Debug.Print "Critical error: " & Err.Description & "[Form1." & FUNC_NAME & "]", Timer
End Function

Public Function InitParamHelper( _
            ByVal vValue As Variant, _
            ByVal eType As ADODB.DataTypeEnum, _
            Optional ByVal Size As Long, _
            Optional Direction As ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum = adParamInput, _
            Optional ByVal Name As String, _
            Optional ByVal Precision As Long, _
            Optional ByVal NumericScale As Long) As ADODB.Parameter
    Const FUNC_NAME     As String = "InitParamHelper"
    Const DBL_NUM_LIMIT As Double = 10# ^ 12 ' 922337203685477#
    Const EMPTY_GUID    As String = "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}"

    On Error GoTo EH
    Select Case eType
    Case adVarChar, adVarWChar, adChar, adWChar
        '--- trim varchar params'
        If Not IsNull(vValue) And Not IsEmpty(vValue) Then
            vValue = Left$(vValue, Size)
        End If
    Case adLongVarChar, adLongVarWChar, adLongVarBinary
        '--- fix default size for BLOB params'
        If Size = 0 Then
            Size = -1
        End If
    Case adDBTimeStamp
        If CDate(vValue) = CLng(CDate(vValue)) Then
            eType = adDBDate
        ElseIf CLng(CDate(vValue)) = 0 Then
            eType = adDBTime
        Else
            eType = adDate
        End If
    Case adNumeric, adDecimal, adCurrency
        '--- numeric range'
        If IsNumeric(vValue) Then
            If vValue > DBL_NUM_LIMIT Then
                vValue = DBL_NUM_LIMIT
            ElseIf vValue < -DBL_NUM_LIMIT Then
                vValue = -DBL_NUM_LIMIT
            End If
        End If
    Case adGUID
        If Direction = adParamInput Then
            If IsEmpty(vValue) Then
                vValue = EMPTY_GUID
            End If
        End If
    End Select
    Set InitParamHelper = New ADODB.Parameter
    InitParamHelper.Name = Name
    InitParamHelper.Type = eType
    InitParamHelper.Direction = Direction
    InitParamHelper.Size = Size
    InitParamHelper.Value = vValue
    If Precision > 0 Then
        InitParamHelper.Precision = Precision
    End If
    If NumericScale > 0 Then
        InitParamHelper.NumericScale = NumericScale
    End If
    Exit Function
EH:
    Debug.Print "Critical error: " & Err.Description & "[Form1." & FUNC_NAME & "]", Timer
    Set InitParamHelper = Nothing
End Function
```

Note that `NUMERIC(18)` gets parsed as `NUMERIC(18, 0)` which has 0 digits after floating-point but you use `Round(..., 2)` for these params so probably an error. Just use `NUMERIC(18, 2)` or evern better `DECIMAL(19, 2)` as precision 18 and precision 19 use the same 5 bytes for storage.

Also note that `sp_` prefix is reserved for system stored procedures, don't use it for user-defined stored procedures. You have to come up with different prefix like `usp_` for `sp` (without underscore).